# Doctrine/Symfony2 get data from tables in relationship

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, doctrine-orm, relationship

I have an table Article that is in relationship with Steps (OneToMany) and Steps with Article ManyToOne.

I get Articles with:

```
$articles = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository("IftodiDesignBundle:Article")
            ->findAll();
```

And with foreach I want to show all Articles and Steps:

```
foreach($articles as $article)
    {
        $steps = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository("IftodiDesignBundle:Steps")
                ->createQueryBuilder('s')
                ->where('s.article = \''.$article.'\'')
                ->getQuery()
                ->execute();

        echo "<b>".$article->getTitle()."</b><br />";
        echo $article->getText()."<br />";
    }
```

I don't know how to get data from table Steps usign the table Article and method getSteps() that is generated with Doctrine.

Please help me.

---

Thanks for the answer.

In table Article I have:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Steps", mappedBy="Steps",cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id_article")
 */
protected $steps;
```

In table Steps:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Article", inversedBy="steps")
 * 
 */
protected $article;
```

When I do:

```
 $articles = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository("IftodiDesignBundle:Article")
            ->findAll();
```

If I do:

```
foreach($articles as $article)
    {
        $steps = $article->getSteps();
```

I recieve error:

```
 Notice: Undefined index: Steps in /var/www/design/vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php line 1280
```

---

If I do that:

```
    $articles = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository("IftodiDesignBundle:Article")
            ->findAll();
    foreach($articles as $article)
    {
        //Queries to DB
         $steps = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository("IftodiDesignBundle:Steps")
            ->findBy(array(
                "article"    => $article->getId()
            ));
         $media = $this->getDoctrine()
                 ->getRepository("IftodiDesignBundle:Media")
                 ->findBy(array(
                     "step" => $steps[0]->getId()
                 ));
```

I can obtain data that I need, but here are more interrogation to DB.

Comment: I know little about Doctrine, but I would instinctively try ´$article->getSteps();´. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, a tried, but a recieve and error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete `@ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id_article")` from your annotation - doctrine will map your association into MySQL with sensible defaults.

Once you have deleted, regenerate your SQL: `doctrine:schema:update --force`

Furthermore if you are looping over your articles to get your steps, you are better off writing a custom method in your repository otherwise each time you call `->getSteps()` Doctrine will make an SQL call (imagine looping over 100 articles - you would end up making 101 calls to the database!)

To avoid this you can put a method like so in your repository

```
public function all()
{
    $queryBuilder = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

    $queryBuilder
        ->select('Article', 'Steps')
        ->from('IftodiDesignBundle:Article')
        ->leftJoin('Article.steps', 'Steps')
    ;

    // consider using ->getArrayResult() to use less memory
    return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult(); 
}
```

I put together a few more best practices in a [blog post](http://www.uvd.co.uk/blog/some-doctrine-2-best-practices/)

Comment: thanks. I also have the problem. I modified the Annotation how you said, Droped and Recreated the database. Now the error is: Notice: Undefined index: Steps in /var/www/design/vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/SqlWalker.php line 746 ; @PeterSmith please help to solve.

Comment: Here is the var_dump($steps) when I do $steps = $article->getSteps();  http://pastebin.com/CZsxjRcg

Answer (score 0):

Well,

Assuming that you have the following relation in Article model:

```
/** 
* @OneToMany(targetEntity="Step", mappedBy="article")
* @JoinColumn(name="id_article", referencedColumnName="id_article_in_step")
*/
protected $steps;

public function getSteps(){ return $this->steps; }
```

you will be able to do `$article->getSteps();`